# More problems with rosinstall on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: rosinstall, macos-snowleopard, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just got an error on running rosinstall this morning on my MacBook. Previously this ran fine. What's perhaps changed is that I updated my macports last night and among the updates was one to boost, which is relevant because this was the error output from rosinstall:

```
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/rosplay
  Undefined symbols:
    "boost::filesystem3::path::extension() const", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
    "boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()", referenced from:
        ros::record::Player::open(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, ros::Time, bool)in rosplay.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/rosplay] Error 1
```

Then a bit later:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/rosinstall", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('rosinstall==0.5.16', 'rosinstall')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 442, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1167, in run_script
    exec script_code in namespace, namespace
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 556, in <module>
    
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/rosinstall-0.5.16-py2.6.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/rosinstall", line 547, in rosinstall_main
    
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 462, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'source /Users/john_muccigrosso/ros/setup.sh && rosmake ros ros_comm --rosdep-install' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Suggestions? (I realize that this is similar to several other recent questions, but it seems different in that there's no complaint about yaml. I have also reselected python 2.6, redid an easy_install of pyyaml and rosinstall, all with the same results.

(BTW, I would have commented on one of those other questions, but the q & a format of this forum really doesn't encourage that.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9535/more-problems-with-rosinstall-on-mac-os-10.6/) by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2011-03-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is definitely a problem with the latest version of boost (1.46.1). I went to macports and did

```
port activate boost @1.45.0_2
```

to return to the earlier version of boost, and then rosinstall worked fine. I don't know whether the problem lies in boost or ros, but there it is.

---

Originally posted by [Eponymous](https://answers.ros.org/users/196/eponymous/) with karma: 255 on 2011-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1